# Manejo de datos dentro de un data.frame

Tags: r

El archivo countries.csv contiene las variables de las siguientes variables de los 3234 condados de Estados Unidos: identificador (codecounty); nombre del condado (county); nombre del estado al que pertenece (state); numero de habitantes(population) y superficie, en millas al cuadrado (area).

Debo agrupar los datos de tal manera de que me genere un data.frame que contenga los estados que al menos 2 condados.

El siguiente es el codigo que he logrado escribir. Sin embargo, no logro filtrar los datos del data.frame E2 para que me muestre los estados con dos o mas condados.

```
country=read.csv("countries.csv")

E2=sqldf("select state, count(*) as condados        
        from country
        group by state
        order by  condados desc, state asc
       ")

str(E2)
E2
head(E2)
tail(E2)
```

Mi pregunta es: ¿Alguien sabe como puedo filtrar el data.frame E2 para lograr filtrar los estados que tengan mas de 2 condados?

Gracias a todos :)

Comment: Si tu duda ha sido resuelta, deberías aceptar la respuesta (click en el tick verde) para que la comunidad sepa que tu pregunta ha sido respondida adecuadamente y así sea de mayor ayuda al resto.

Comment: Perdon, crei que ya lo habia hecho. Acabo de marcar la respuesta como resuelta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes hacer uso del la clausula `HAVING` que vendría ser un `WHERE` pero posterior al agrupamiento.

```
select state, 
       count(*) as condados        
       from country
       group by state
       having count(*) > 2
       order by  condados desc, state asc
```

Comment: Gracias, me sirvio perfectamente :)
No sabia que existia el having.